# What does "1" in "D2D1" stands for?

Tags: winapi, direct2d

`D2D1` is the namespace for Direct2D technology in Win32. However I don't understand the etymology of this name. The `D2D` part most likely refers to **D**﻿irect﻿**2D**, however the last **1** puzzles me...

There are also a lot of classes with "1" as a suffix: `IDWriteFactory1`, `IDWriteFont1`, `IDWriteTextLayout1`, etc. — what is their purpose, and difference from the similar objects without the suffix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

COM interfaces are usually named with increasing numbers to allow for versioning.  Once a COM interface has been published publically, COM rules dictate that the interface is not allowed to be changed anymore, or else compatibility with existing code breaks.  If new functionality needs to be added, a new interface has to be exposed.  Let's take `IDWriteFactory1` for example.  Today, that is a first release interface.  In the future, maybe `IDWriteFactory2` will be added that extends `IDWriteFactory1` with new methods.  Existing code is preserved, since they don't know anything about `IDWriteFactory2`, but new code could create an `IDWriteFactory1` object and query it to see if it supports `IDWriteFactory2` and if so then use the newer methods as needed.

The naming of the `D2D1` namespace is likely similar.  It is probably being used for versioning purposes (Direct2D v1 ?).  Maybe there will be a `D2D2` (Direct2D v2) namespace added in the future for things that don't fit in the existing Direct2D architecture.  Who knows for sure.

Comment: IDWriteFactory2 was actually added in Windows 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280448(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: However Direct2D 1.1 did not up the interface number, even though they've added stuff too; the new stuff is not in the D2D interface itself though, but in ID2D1DeviceContext, which is in the new d2d1_1.h (added to Windows 8): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198239.aspx.